# Type inference in SML

Tags: sml

I'm currently learning SML and I have a question about something I have no name for. Lets call it "type alias" for the moment. Suppose I have the following datatype definition:

```
datatype 'a stack = Stack of 'a list;
```

I now want to add an explicit "empty stack" type. I can to this by adding it to the datatype:

```
datatype 'a stack = emptystack | Stack of 'a list;
```

Now I can pattern match a function like "push":

```
fun push (emptystack) (e:'a) = Stack([e])
  | push (Stack(list):'a stack) (e:'a) = Stack(e::list);
```

The problem here is that `Stack([])` and `emptystack` are different but I want them to be the same. So every time SML encounters an `Stack([])` it should "know" that this is `emptystack` (in case of push it should then use the emptystack match).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just for the record, it's called *inference*, not *interference*. The SML compiler *infers* the type of an expression. It doesn't *interfere* :)

Comment: This begs the question: *Why* do you even want to do that? How is the second version of `stack` preferable to the first? Usually, one wants to remove redundant cases rather than introducing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No, it is not possible.

You can create type aliases with the code

```
type number = int

val foo : number -> int -> number =
 fn a => fn b => a+b

val x : int = foo 1 3;
val y : number = foo 1 3;
```

However, as the name says, it only works for types. Your question goes for value constructors, which there is no syntax for.

Answer (score 2):

Such an aliasing is not possible in SML.

Instead, you should design your datatypes to be unambiguous in their representation, if that is what you desire.

You'd probably be better suited with something that resembles the definition of `'a list` more:

```
datatype 'a stack = EmptyStack | Stack of 'a * 'a stack;
```

This has the downside of not letting you use the list functions on it, but you do get an explicit empty stack constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is for one value `emptystack` to be synonymous with another value `Stack []`, you could call what you are looking for "value aliases". Values that are compared with the built-in operator `=` or pattern matching will not allow for aliases.

You can achieve this by creating your own equality operator, but you will lose the ability to use the built-in `=` (since Standard ML does not support custom operator overloading) as well as the ability to pattern match on the value constructors of your type.

Alternatively, you can construct a normal form for your type and always compare the normal form. Whenever practically feasible, follow Sebastian's suggestion of no ambiguity. There might be situations in which an unambiguous algebraic type will be much more complex than a simpler one that allows the same value to be represented in different ways.